# Hibernate session is closed when object is loaded in Spring Request Filter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an *AuthenticationFilter* that reads a token from the HTTP-Request, loads the user object from the database and sets it to the *SecurityContextHolder*:

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(resultOfAuthentication);`

Now in the request handler in a controller-class i want to access a field of the User-object the is lazily loaded. The problem is that I get a **LazyInitializationException** because the session is closed:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: a.b.c.User.devices, could
>   not initialize proxy - no Session

Any ideas how I can keep the session open until the request is finished? So that I can lazily load fields of the User-Object?

Comment: You can configure it in web.xml 
  <filter>
   <filter-name>openSession</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>openSession</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

You would have to enclose that call inside your @Transactional method or to move the transaction boundaries higher up in the call hierarchy, so that invocation is included as well.

Other options would be to:

- Eagerly fetch all the required dependencies while the session is still opened (`join fetch`)
- Use `Hibernate.initialize(user.getAddresses());` inside of the transactional context
- Simply call size method on the depenedent colletions to initialze them `user.getAddresses().size`:

Comment: Can I annotate the *doHandle(..)* method of my *AuthenticationFilter* with @Transactional ? The *AuthenticationFilter* is not initialized by Spring. I just initialize it in my Spring Security config.

Comment: yes you can.. here is one of the post about it .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278783/spring-transactions-hibernate-filters

Comment: Did this work? I tried addind the @transactional annotation on the doHandle() method but I still have the same problem.